# How do I use derived classes if I only have a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, inventory

So here's what I got in a nutshell.

1. I have a base item class from which, potions, equipment, spells, etc.. are derived and several classes are derived from those and so on. Note: some derived classes have non-virtual class-specific member functions / data types.
2. I have also created a "random" armor/weapon generator.

What I want to have is an inventory kind of like this:

```
struct Hero_Inventory
{
   std::vector<Spell*> Spell_Inventory;
   std::vector<Potion*> Potion_Inventory;
   std::vector<Equipment*> Equipment_Inventory; 

   Hero_Inventory() {}
};
```

Creating a container (inventory) for my spells and potions has been pretty straight forward. As they will be predefined. Using polymorphism and pointers wont be a problem

My main problem is figuring out to store and use (ex. access the weapon-class's specific member functions) my randomly generated weapons / armor (which are both derived from Equipment).

I would like for all of my "Equipment" to be in one container.

I'm generating all of my Equipment in a few functions so when I finish the generation process and end up with something like this:

```
Equipment * TestArmor = new Armor(/* Bunch of parameters go here */);
```

I don't know what to do with it, because as soon as that function goes out of scope I loose that pointer. And without pointers / referencing I can't use polymorphism, which is allowing me to keep my Equipment all in one container.

I'm really lost at this point and I'm looking for any suggestions or alternatives people can suggest. If you need more code I'll post it, just tell me what part(s) your interested in.

Sorry if I've been vague, this is my fist post. I'm usually pretty good at figuring things out on my own but this thing has me beat. If anyone needs more information ask and I'll try to provide it.

Thanks in advance,
-Ryan

Comment: What is the question here? Why dont you add that to `Equipment_Inventory`?

Comment: Don't query the specific weapons for their properties, tell them what to do through a uniform interface. They can decide what they can do.

Comment: @Karthik T: The reason I can't add it is because as soon as my armor generator function is finished my pointer gets turned into garbage. because at that point, it is now out of scope. Right? I'm pretty sure that's how dynamic memory works.

Comment: @RyanNolan: That's not accurate. The pointer is out of scope but the value (ie. the address of your `TestArmor` object) can be stored as long as that object is live.

Comment: @Peter Wood: that's an interesting way of addressing the problem. One that I had not considered before. I got really caught up using polymorphism. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: @RyanNolan `myhero.Equipment_Inventory.push_back(TestArmor)` will do exactly what you want with no gotchas, except for the need to `delete` in the end. It is only the pointer that goes out of scope, and if you add to the list, the memory itself stays on for you to access later.

Comment: @RyanNolan That is polymorphism. You derive from `Equipment` *so that* you can have a uniform interface for manipulating the objects.

Comment: @Peter Wood: I knew that but I just got so caught up in the way of cheating (via casting) using polymorphism that forgot about the real reason for polymorphism.

Comment: @Karthik T: Thanks. I don't know what made me start thinking otherwise.

Huge thanks to both of you.

Comment: No need to mention "solved" in the title; this question will display differently on the list pages once you click the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a uniform interface for manipulating the `Equipment` objects:

```
class Equipment {
public:
    virtual void render(Renderer& renderer) = 0;
    virtual void createController(ControllerManager& controllerManager) = 0;
    virtual void load(std::istream& input) = 0;
    virtual void save(std::ostream& output) = 0;
};
```

The function `createController` is interesting as the equipment will be able to tell the `ControllerManager` how to create something that will manipulate its exact values.

If you want a function which allows interaction with other `Equipment` objects, you probably need the [`Visitor Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This is a way of introducing polymorphism based on multiple types rather than a single type.